# Product cart in blank when refresh site

Tags: php, html

When you enter to www.mutantshop.mx and add products to cart all is fine and all products appear in the float right cart, like this image:

[image: Capture number 1]

But the issue comes when you try to refresh the page with <kbd>F5</kbd> or try to navigate to another page and later try click on the basket cart and it appears in blank without product details like this image:

[image: Capture number 2]

I have tried a lot of tricks to solve this but I can't do it, really I hope can help me with this! regards

Comment: Could you please consider sharing the code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Its because on page load initialization cart is hidden. If you add item into cart it will run event or fucntion which cart show up.

You can call this event or function if cart has an item at page load.

This is tested working example in vanilla js:

```
function pageLoadShowCart() {
  if(document.querySelectorAll('.xoo-wsc-container .xoo-wsc-product').length) {
    // call event or function which show cart
    document.getElementsByClassName('xoo-wsc-basket')[0].click();
  }
}

pageLoadShowCart();
```

The code above have two steps. First try find product already in cart and cart not empty then simulate click on cart icon. On page load it open cart if is not empty.

This shoud be on index.[html,php,asp].

Also you can make this `IF` in your main language instead of javascript.

**=== EDIT ===**
If not work it can be caused by cart widget load. In some cases js need time for load.

Try wrap the code into timeout function. It may help.

```
function pageLoadShowCart() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(document.querySelectorAll('.xoo-wsc-container .xoo-wsc-product').length) {
      // call event or function which show cart
      document.getElementsByClassName('xoo-wsc-basket')[0].click();
    }
  }, 150);
}
```

Comment: I have tried add the code with a custom js but i cant solve

Comment: @DevelabMéxico and what not work? I tested this in console and work well. You can try wrap it into Timeout function with 100ms or more what happend.

Comment: I have added again the code and look the site, its down :S

Comment: @DevelabMéxico i updated answer. Put it in index at bottom of page. It shoud work.